# undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'

Tags: c++, cmake, x11

I'm tying to compile the program from [c++ fast screenshots in linux for use with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988164/c-fast-screenshots-in-linux-for-use-with-opencv) using CMakeLists.txt.

`cmake` runs good, but when using `make` I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demoScreenShot.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/demoScreenShot.dir/build.make:112: demoScreenShot] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/demoScreenShot.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
# Personal Project (Necesary)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)


project(demoScreenShot)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
# OpenCV
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

# X11 dependecies. It throws the same error using this block or not using it
include_directories( /usr/X11/include )  # It fails with this line or without it
link_directories( /usr/X11/lib ) # It fails with this line or without it
set (OPENGL_LIBRARIES GL GLU X11)  # It fails with this line or without it
```

My main.cpp

```cpp
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>


void ImageFromDisplay(std::vector<uint8_t>& Pixels, int& Width, int& Height, int& BitsPerPixel)
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XWindowAttributes* attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, attributes);
    // XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    // XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);

    // Width = attributes.width;
    // Height = attributes.height;
    Width = attributes -> width;
    Height = attributes -> height;

    XImage* img = XGetImage(display, root, 0, 0 , Width, Height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    BitsPerPixel = img->bits_per_pixel;
    Pixels.resize(Width * Height * 4);

    memcpy(&Pixels[0], img->data, Pixels.size());

    XDestroyImage(img);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}


int main()
{
    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;
    int Bpp = 0;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;

    ImageFromDisplay(Pixels, Width, Height, Bpp);

    if (Width && Height)
    {
        //Mat(Size(Height, Width), Bpp > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &Pixels[0]); 
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(Height, Width, Bpp > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &Pixels[0]);

        namedWindow("WindowTitle", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Display window", img);

        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I also tried making the variable attributes a pointer, but it didn't work!

How can I successfully compile this code?

Comment: You don't link your project to X11, `OPENGL_LIBRARIES` is set but unused.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to successfully compiled the program.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

project(demoScreenShot)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# OpenCV
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/X11)

set(X11)
link_directories( /usr/lib/X11 )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} X11)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).