# Opencv fails to isolate color when image is a local screenshot

Tags: c++, opencv, x11

Problem:
When i isolate the background of the screenshot i get a pure white image, instead a pure white image with black dots
Solution:
Save screenshot and reloaded into a brand new variable

I have finally know what causes this behaviour, i have found an ugly solution but have yet know what causes it and obviously have yet to found a proper (more professional) solution.

My program first takes a screenshot in a Linux OS, here is the code:

```
/*
   Takes screenshot using X11 libraries

   Program taken from:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988164/c-fast-screenshots-in-linux-for-use-with-opencv

   There are faster ways to take screenshots, but this is the most upvoted one lol ;)
*/
cv::Mat imageFromDisplay(int *width, int *height, int *bitsPerPixel, std::vector<std::uint8_t> &pixels)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);

    *width = attributes.width;
    *height = attributes.height;

    XImage *img = XGetImage(display, root, 0, 0 , *width, *height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    *bitsPerPixel = img->bits_per_pixel;
    pixels.resize(*width * *height * 4);

    memcpy(&pixels[0], img->data, pixels.size());

    XDestroyImage(img);
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    // Convert X11 screenshot into cv::Mat object
    return cv::Mat(*height, *width, *bitsPerPixel > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &pixels[0]);
}
```

And the using that cv::mat that i returned in previous function i use the following function.

```
// This imgScreenshot is the same cv::Mat from imageFromDisplay
int foo(const cv::Mat &imgScreenshot)
{
    int rh=255, rl=99, gh=255, gl=67, bh=92, bl=0;
    cv::Mat table, tableIso, element;
    cv::Rect2d roi;

    // Croping screenshot to get only our ROI (Region Of Interest)
    roi.x = ROI_TABLE_X;
    roi.y = ROI_TABLE_Y;
    roi.width = ROI_TABLE_WIDTH;
    roi.height = ROI_TABLE_HEIGHT;
    table = imgScreenshot(roi);

    // Here is where openCV misbehave, tableIso turns out to be a pure white image
    // which it shouldn't, it should have some black spots
    element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5));
    cv::inRange(table, cv::Scalar(bl, gl, rl), cv::Scalar(bh, gh, rh), tableIso);
    cv::bitwise_not(tableIso, tableIso);
    cv::erode(tableIso, tableIso, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(tableIso, tableIso, element);
}
```

This is how i solved the problem which is the same code as before, but i just
save the table (the cropped region) and the reloaded in a new variable.
And use that variable to apply the isolation.

```
// This imgScreenshot is the same cv::Mat from imageFromDisplay
int foo(const cv::Mat &imgScreenshot)
{
    int rh=255, rl=99, gh=255, gl=67, bh=92, bl=0;
    cv::Mat table, tableIso, element;
    cv::Rect2d roi;

    // Croping screenshot to get only our ROI (Region Of Interest)
    roi.x = ROI_TABLE_X;
    roi.y = ROI_TABLE_Y;
    roi.width = ROI_TABLE_WIDTH;
    roi.height = ROI_TABLE_HEIGHT;
    table = imgScreenshot(roi);

    // New Code
    cv::imwrite("table.jpg", table);
    cv::Mat newTable = cv::imread("table.jpg");

    // Same code as before, but this time it works like a charm
    element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5));
    cv::inRange(newTable, cv::Scalar(bl, gl, rl), cv::Scalar(bh, gh, rh), tableIso);
    cv::bitwise_not(tableIso, tableIso);
    cv::erode(tableIso, tableIso, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(tableIso, tableIso, element);
}
```

So this lead me into thinking that maybe the root of my problem is the way that i'm taking the screenshot.
Because i have also tried a function like this (in another program). That didn't have the problem that i face when i take the screenshot.

```
// Here i load the image and therefore it doesn't have the problem of the pure white image isolation
int foo()
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1]);

    int rh=255, rl=99, gh=255, gl=67, bh=92, bl=0;
    cv::Mat table, tableIso, element;
    cv::Rect2d roi;

    // Croping screenshot to get only our ROI (Region Of Interest)
    roi.x = ROI_TABLE_X;
    roi.y = ROI_TABLE_Y;
    roi.width = ROI_TABLE_WIDTH;
    roi.height = ROI_TABLE_HEIGHT;
    table = src(roi);

    // Same code as before, but this time it works like a charm
    element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5));
    cv::inRange(table, cv::Scalar(bl, gl, rl), cv::Scalar(bh, gh, rh), tableIso);
    cv::bitwise_not(tableIso, tableIso);
    cv::erode(tableIso, tableIso, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(tableIso, tableIso, element);
}
```

I know i have solved this problem, but my goal is to have a fast program or at least try to optimize things.
Saving a cv::Mat as an image and the realoading it into another cv::Mat seems like unoptimize and slow way of doing things to me, so even thought it works i really don't like it.

```
    cv::Mat table = imgScreenshot(roi);
    cv::imwrite("table.jpg", table);
    cv::Mat newTable = cv::imread("table.jpg");
```

I know you might think that the imgScreenshot is broken but i have sucessfully cropped the image (ROI) and also used this openCV functions into a cropped cv::Mat fron imgScreenshot.

```
// Take X11 screenshot
cv::Mat imgScreenshot = imageFromDisplay(&width, &height, &bitsPerPixel, pixels);
// Cropping screenshot
roi.x = ROI_CLEAN_LABEL_X;
roi.y = ROI_CLEAN_LABEL_Y;
roi.width = ROI_CLEAN_LABEL_WIDTH;
roi.height = ROI_CLEAN_LABEL_HEIGHT;
cv::Mat cleanLabelSquare = imgScreenshot(roi);

cvtColor(cleanLabelSquare, labelMask, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV); 
// ...
cvtColor(cleanLabelSquare, labelMask, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

So it doesn't seem like the screenshot is that broken to me, since i have applied cvtColor into a cv::Mat that comes from the original screenshot.

Thanks for reading till the end.
This is the first time i work on background isolation, so maybe i might be doing something wrong.

What do you think causes this ugly behaviour?
And is there another way of solving this problem that can be more effecient than my solution?

Edit:
I have also tried changing the argument from this:

```
int foo(const cv::Mat &imgScreenshot)
```

to the following (without success):

```
int foo(cv::Mat &imgScreenshot)
// and
int foo(cv::Mat imgScreenshot)
```